# When should I request a Facebook access token?

Tags: iphone, facebook, graph, token

Facebook changed their Graph API recently to require an access token. Therefore I quickly made a Facebook application to be able to retrieve an access token, use a URL similar to the one below, generated my access token and implemented the token in my iPhone application. Lately I have been thinking about if I have done something wrong. Should I request the access token everytime a user of my application retrieves data from the Graph API? I am starting to doubt whether or not the access token is unique to each user or just to the Facebook application.

Can I hardcode an access token into my application or should I make a request on the URL below every time I need to retrieve data through the Graph API?

I am generating my access token with the following URL:

> [https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=*MYID*&client_secret=*MY_SECRET*&grant_type=client_credentials](https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=%2aMYID%2a&client_secret=%2aMY_SECRET%2a&grant_type=client_credentials)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Access token granted by user have expiration time. If token expired then you need to request it again. But if you ask user to grant you "offline_access" permissions then you'll have almost not limited access token. You can store it in database or file and use next time.

Here FB documentation about permissions:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/

> Enables your app to perform authorized
>   requests on behalf of the user at any
>   time. By default, most access tokens
>   expire after a short time period to
>   ensure applications only make requests
>   on behalf of the user when the are
>   actively using the application. This
>   permission makes the access token
>   returned by our OAuth endpoint
>   long-lived.